# jQuery UI checkboxes misbehaving when cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a table of inputs that automatically adds a new row when you enter text in one of the inputs on the bottom line. For the most part, it works fine. However, I'm having some trouble with jQuery UI checkbox buttons.

The checkbox buttons are supposed to change their icon when clicked. This works fine for the original buttons, but the cloned button that appears when you add a new row doesn't work properly.

You can see it [in jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cugb6/1/). To replicate the issue, put some text in the third input down. You'll see that a fourth row appears. If you press the fourth checkbox, you'll see the third checkbox is the one whose icon changes. The wrong button also gets ui-state-focus but doesn't actually get focus, which really baffles me, though the correct button does get ui-state-active and seems, as far as I can tell, to evaluate as having been checked properly.

To be clear, the two checkboxes do *not* have the same ID, and their labels are for the right checkbox - the createNewRow() function takes care of that. If you comment out the line that turns the checkboxes into jQuery UI checkboxes, you'll see everything works fine. If you console.log the value of $(this).attr('id') in the buttonSwitchCheck function, you'll see that it has the right ID there too - if you click the fourth button, it'll tell you that the id of $(this) is "test4", but it's "test3" (the third button) that gets the icon change.

I'm going mad staring at this and I'd appreciate any help people can give. Here's the code:

```
// Turns on and off an icon as the checkbox changes from checked to unchecked.
function buttonSwitchCheck() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        $(this).button("option", "icons", {
            primary: "ui-icon-circle-check"
        });
    } else {
        $(this).button("option", "icons", {
            primary: "ui-icon-circle-close"
        });
    }
}

// Add a new row at the bottom once the user starts filling out the bottom blank row.
function createNewRow() {
    // Identify the row and clone it, including the bound events.
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var table = row.closest("table");
    var newRow = row.clone(true);
    // Set all values (except for buttons) to blank for the new row.
    newRow.find('.ssheet').not('.button').val('');
    // Find elements that require an ID (mostly elements with labels like checkboxes) and increment the ID.
    newRow.find('.ssheetRowId').each(function () {
        var idArr = $(this).attr('id').match(/^(.*?)([0-9]*)$/);
        var idNum = idArr[2] - 0 + 1;
        var newId = idArr[1] + idNum;
        $(this).attr('id', newId);
        $(this).siblings('label.ssheetGetRowId').attr('for', newId);
    });
    // Add the row to the table.
    newRow.appendTo(table);
    // Remove the old row's ability to create a new row.
    row.removeClass('ssheetNewRow');
    row.find(".ssheet").unbind('change', createNewRow);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Activate jQuery UI checkboxes.
    $(".checkButton").button().bind('change', buttonSwitchCheck).each(buttonSwitchCheck);

    // When text is entered on the bottom row, add a new row.
    $(".ssheetNewRow").find(".ssheet").not('.checkButton').bind('change', createNewRow);
});
```

**EDIT:** I was able to find a solution, which I'll share with the ages. Thanks to "Funky Dude" below, who inspired me to start thinking along the right track.

The trick is to destroy the jQuery UI button in the original row before the clone, then reinitializing it immediately afterwards for both the original row and the copy. You don't need to unbind and rebind the change event - it's just the jQuery UI buttons which have trouble. In the createNewRow function:

```
row.find('.checkButton').button('destroy');
var newRow = row.clone(true);
row.find('.checkButton').add(newRow.find('.checkButton')).button().each(buttonSwitchCheck);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using deep clone, which also clones the event handler. in your create new row function, try unbinding the change event then rebind on the clone.

Comment: Ah - but what I hadn't tried was destroying the button before it was cloned, then recreating it afterward!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the newer method `.on`, that allows for delegation, which should help with the dynamic changes to your DOM:

```
$(".checkButton").button().each(buttonSwitchCheck);
$("table").on("change", ".checkButton", buttonSwitchCheck);
```

I'm not sure, but it might help with not having to worry about binding events to specific elements.

Also, you could use it for the textbox `change` event:

```
$("table").on("change", ".ssheetNewRow .ssheet:not(.checkButton)", createNewRow);
```

Here's your fiddle with my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/Cugb6/3/

It doesn't function any different, but to me, it's a little cleaner. I thought it would've fixed your problem, but obviously hasn't, due to problems with the `button` widget.

And funny enough, it doesn't seem they "support" cloning: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7959

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem. Thanks, though! I'll have to look into the `.on` method more; it looks useful.

Comment: @flyingGhoti I really thought it would, but then after testing with your fiddle, realized it's problems with the `button` widget. Sorry it didn't fix it, but hopefully it helps with something. I updated my answer with some stuff

Comment: That does have a certain elegance. I may implement the change across the project when I get around to it. As far as jQuery UI not supporting cloning... well, I'll just say that's useful to know and leave it at that.

Comment: @flyingGhoti In certain ways, it's elegant. `on` should be used for all event bindings. If you want to use it like `bind`, just provide 2 parameters - the event name "change", and then the callback. If you want to use delegation, which is good for dynamic contents in a container or where there are many elements to bind an event to, they I would suggest it. So for example, if your table were a static table and had hundreds of rows, all of which had a button that needed a `click` event, then it's probably more _efficient_ and _clean_ to use delegation. Even more both for dynamic contents :)

Comment: The more complicated my project gets, the more I realize what great advice this was. Thanks, Ian! It may not have solved the first problem, but it's solved a lot since.

Comment: @flyingGhoti Awesome, glad it helped somewhere else! Yeah, I think one day I just decided I'm going to use delegation as often as I can where applicable, and I feel like things are easier to manage. There's plenty of cases not to use `on` delegation, so that's obviously up to you, but plenty can be approved by using it. I'm guessing you read up on the jQuery API Docs for `on`? http://api.jquery.com/on/